# Difference between antlr4-tools and installation

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm starting gettting my hands dirty with antlr4 and I don't unserstand the difference between **Getting started the easy way using antlr4-tools** and **Installation** decribed in the [Getting started guide](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md).

- Can I choose either one?
- Does antlr4 (easy start) correspond to antlr4 alias (installation)?
- Does antlr4-parse (easy start) correspond to grun alias (installation)?

Comment: The antlr4-tool (`antlr4`) calls `java -cp antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar ...`. https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-tools/blob/10a090aab6ec70217d1d8aa0c2f16c9f1e425861/antlr4_tool_runner.py#L143. What antlr4-tools does is to download for you the .jar and if necessary the Java JRE so you don't need to install all that stuff and pollute your development machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your 3 questions can be answered with a sound "yes" :)

There are (most probably) 2 versions because some people might not have Python installed on their machine.